# Conexion con una base de datos Firebird

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, firebird

Buen día, mi duda surge debido a que no encuentro una gema o forma de utilizar una base de datos de firebird 2.5 en ruby 2.3.0 y rails 5.0.0.1

Deseo crear una conexión alternativa ya que por default utilizó una base de datos mysql, pero necesito insertar, actualizar y comparar datos con la DB de firebird que le pertenece a un sistema ya existente.

De antemano agradezco el apoyo que puedan brindarme.

> Anexo error cuando intento instalar Gem 'fb'

```
Fetching fb 0.8.0
Installing fb 0.8.0 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/fb-0.8.0
/home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby -r
./siteconf20170902-2516-125u1ez.rb extconf.rb
checking for isc_attach_database() in -lfbclient... no
checking for isc_attach_database() in -lgds... no
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

/home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/fb-0.8.0/mkmf.log

current directory:
/home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/fb-0.8.0
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory:
/home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/fb-0.8.0
make "DESTDIR="
compiling fb.c
fb.c:41:19: fatal error: ibase.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
 #include <ibase.h>
               ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [fb.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
/home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/fb-0.8.0 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/fb-0.8.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing fb (0.8.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install fb -v '0.8.0'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  fb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar con la gema [activerecord-fb-adapter](https://github.com/rowland/activerecord-fb-adapter), la cual funciona bien con rails 4.x, pero tendrás que probar para saber si también funciona con rails 5.0.

En caso que no te funcione la anterior, puedes utilizar la gema [fb](https://github.com/rowland/fb)<sup>1</sup>, a través de la cual puedes realizar conexiones directas a la BD sin ningún tipo de ORM (es decir, harías las consultas manuales). La ventaja de esta gema es que te funcionará sin importar tu versión de rails.

---

<sup>1</sup> *La librería **libfbclient.so** no esta incluida en la versión de **firebird 2.5**, por lo tanto es necesario instalar **firebird-dev** para poder instalar la gema.*

Comment: de hecho el de activerecord no puedo utilizarlo, pero con la gema fb no encuentro como utilizarla o añadirla a mi proyecto, intento agregarla como gem 'fb' pero me salta el error gem:Ext:BuildError: Error: Failed to build gem native extension y no encuentro documentación sobre errores o posibles complementos que me hagan falta, actualmente utilizo un ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS

Comment: @DanielRomero ¿Podrías mostrar el log completo del error? (Agrégalo en tu pregunta, no como comentario.)

Comment: ya agregue el error completo que me manda la consola

Comment: @DanielRomero ¿Tienes instalado Firebird en tu máquina local? Si no es así, hazlo y luego intentas de nuevo.

Comment: Si, ya tengo instalado un firebird superclassic 2.5 con todos sus complementos

Comment: Buen día, al parecer la libreria libfbclient.so no esta incluida en la versión de firebird2.5, pero instalando firebird-dev ya me dejo instalar la gema correctamente. Te agradezco la ayuda, saludos @Gerry

Comment: @DanielRomero Gracias por compartir, agregaré la nota en la respuesta para que le sirva a alguien que se encuentre con ese problema más adelante.